# My datastore has no index entries on appspot?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

First I create a index.yaml

```
- kind: Tarifa 2014
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: Date
    direction: desc

- kind: Tarifa 2014
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: Division
  - name: Heat
  - name: Date
    direction: desc
```

Then I put some data in

```
key := datastore.NewKey(s.Context, "Tarifa 2014", "", 0, s.Root)
key, err = datastore.Put(s.Context, key, m)
```

Simple queries work,

```
key := datastore.NewKey(s.Context, "Tarifa 2014", "", id, s.Root)
err = datastore.Get(s.Context, key, &m)
```

but this does do not because my index is still empty?

```
datastore.NewQuery(e).Ancestor(s.Root).Filter("Division =", d).Filter("Heat =", h).Order("-Date")
```

Same for this, it also does not work?

```
datastore.NewQuery(e).Ancestor(s.Root).Order("-Date")
```

My index looks like this on appspot.com?

[image]

My datastore looks like this on appspot.com

[image]

Note that on localhost:8080 all queries work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason that is not clear, if I use `Namespace` , indexed queries break on appspot.com

```
c2 := endpoints.NewContext(r)
c, err := appengine.Namespace(c2, "")
if err != nil {return err}
```

You need to use endpoints context directly without a namespace.

```
c := endpoints.NewContext(r)
```